# How to generalize Matlab function?

Tags: matlab, function

I have a Matlab function.  I need to generalize this function.  This code’s aim is to check this IndicMPs are in  the TableTemp, if it is there, then we extract relevant age limits, such as:  Age_Limite_DC, Age_Limite_IT, Age_Limite_Ch and Transfert_Prime_IT_DC.  My idea is to generalize, passing parameters to find out the "Type_pret" is.(May be I'm wrong)  Since I'm beginner to Matlab can someone help me to encode a more generic function that can be used in a more general context?

```
function Structure = optimisation_function()

Data = load('Data.mat');

Structure = Data.Structure;
TableTemp = Data.TableTemp;


Age_Limite_DC          = zeros(size(Structure,1),1);
Age_Limite_IT          = zeros(size(Structure,1),1);
Age_Limite_CH          = zeros(size(Structure,1),1);
Transfert_Prime_IT_DC  = zeros(size(Structure,1),1);

for IndexMPAL = 1 : length(Structure.AnneeSouscription)

    % Determine Type_Pret (Loan Type)
    if ~isempty(strfind(Structure.Type_Pret{IndexMPAL},'A'))
        Type_Pret = 'A';
    elseif ~isempty(strfind(Structure.Type_Pret{IndexMPAL},'B'))
        Type_Pret = 'B';
    elseif ~isempty(strfind(Structure.Type_Pret{IndexMPAL},'C'))
        Type_Pret = 'C';
    elseif ~isempty(strfind(Structure.Type_Pret{IndexMPAL},'D'))
        Type_Pret = 'D';
    elseif ~isempty(strfind(Structure.Type_Pret{IndexMPAL},'E'))
        Type_Pret = 'E';
    end
    MP_CP       = Structure.NomCodeProduit(IndexMPAL);
    MP_AnSous   = Structure.AnneeSouscription(IndexMPAL);
    MP_TypePret = Type_Pret;
    IndicCP     = strcmp(MP_CP, TableTemp.CodeProduit);
    IndicAS     = MP_AnSous== TableTemp.AnneeSouscription;
    IndicTP     = strcmp(MP_TypePret, TableTemp.TypePret);
    IndicMP     = IndicCP & IndicAS & IndicTP;        

    if ~any(IndicMP)
        Msg = strcat('CodeProduct:',MP_CP{1}, ', Année Souscription:', num2str(MP_AnSous), ', Type Prêt:', MP_TypePret);
        error('Error', Msg)
    else
        Age_Limite_DC(IndexMPAL,1) = TableTemp.Age_Limite_DC(IndicMP,1);
        Age_Limite_IT(IndexMPAL,1) = TableTemp.Age_Limite_IT(IndicMP,1);
        Age_Limite_CH(IndexMPAL,1) = TableTemp.Age_Limite_CH(IndicMP,1);
        Transfert_Prime_IT_DC(IndexMPAL,1)= 
        TableTemp.Transfert_Prime_IT_DC(IndicMP,1);
    end
end

Structure.Age_Limite_DC          = Age_Limite_DC;
Structure.Age_Limite_IT          = Age_Limite_IT;
Structure.Age_Limite_CH          = Age_Limite_CH;
Structure.Transfert_Prime_IT_DC  = Transfert_Prime_IT_DC;

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if/elseif` can be simplified with a cell array:

```
liststr = {'A','BB','C','D','E'}; % builds a cell array, each cell contains a string
Positive_matches = strfind(liststr,Structure.Type_Pret{IndexMPAL}) % returns a list for each cell of the indices where the element was found (empty if none)
Index = find(~cellfun('isempty', Positive_matches )) % converts the previous list into a logical 0/1 array indicating whether an item was found (1) or not (0)
% if isempty(Index); continue; end % If no index is found, to avoid an error in the next instruction, skips the rest of the code. 
Type_Pret = liststr(Index(1));
```

If the `Type_Pret` are the same in your list and in `Structure? , you can use`strcmp`:

```
liststr = {'A','B','C','D','E'};
if any(strcmp(Structure.Type_Pret,liststr))
    Type_Pret = Structure.Type_Pret
else
    % handle error
end
```

You can also work directly on `Structure.Age_Limite_DC` without using `Age_Limite_DC`.

Comment: Thanks Laure for the answers. For me the First answer is fine. But still I'm confusing to understand what happening exactly at line 3, 4, 5. Could you please explain me if you don't mind. and what is the reason ( how you thought)  that I can work directly Structure.Age_Limite_DC without using Age_Limite_DC?

Comment: I edited the first code with comments. You can directly affect values to the Structure, by typing `Structure.Age_Limite_DC = zeros(size(Structure,1),1)` then affecting `Structure.Age_Limite_DC(IndexMPAL,1) = ...`.

Comment: Superb explanation!!! Really this answers helped me lot..As a beginner like me, could you please propose me some tutorials or stuffs to follow. Because I need to get more knowledge about Matlab.  Form beginner to at least intermediate level. Thanks

Comment: One more thing, is that line strictly necessary?  if isempty(Index); continue; end

Comment: One more thing, is that line strictly necessary?  if isempty(Index); continue; end  Because I tried without this line. So the code gave same correct answer. Just to verify with you, as you said "if no index found( that means all are 0 values ) , to avoid an error in the next instruction, skips the rest of the code". it skipped from which lines? Thanks